# Why menu item's text is not visible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap menu item 's text is not visible in below fiddle. Can you please provide the reason?

http://jsfiddle.net/PfzDk/

Same fiddle code copy-pasted here,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <span class="dropdown">   
   <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>  
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </span>
    <a class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">ClickMe</span></a>
    <span class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.btn-group has a font size of zero in this file:

bootstrap-combined.min.css